# Does a solvent with the following properties exist?

Tags: water, solubility, solvents

I am looking for a solvent with these properties:

- It's aprotic.
- At 1 atm, it has a liquid range of at least 0 to 50 degrees Celsius.
- Water can dissolve in it, with a solubility of at least 10g/100g.
- It has a high flash point, preferably 100 degrees Celsius or higher. (Or better, be non-combustible.)

Does a solvent with these properties exist? If it does not exist, what's the reason?

Comment: There's probably several options. [Triethyl phosphate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triethyl_phosphate) seems to fit the bill, from a cursory search. [Propylene carbonate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propylene_carbonate) is even better.

Comment: @nicolau when I click on the WP pages for the compounds above, their links to the safety data sheets do not work. Therefore turn the comment to an answer with a summary of the required miscobility and combustibility properties.

Comment: N-Methyl-2-Pyrrolidone  https://www.m-chemical.co.jp/en/products/departments/mcc/c4/product/1201005_7922.html

Comment: Turns out propylene carbonate actually isn't sufficiently miscible with water at 25 °C, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many examples which clear the requirements. Here is a non-exhaustive list. **I do not claim these data are absolutely accurate** - you should cross-check everything if it matters to you.

A couple of notes:

- Data for solubility of *water in solvents* are significantly sparser than for *solvents in water*. I have collected the latter values, but most of these are miscible with water in any proportion, and if not, they should still clear the requirement.
- Few organic solvents are non-flammable, and the ones that are typically have poor miscibility with water. To get high flash points, you'll need high-boiling solvents.
- I am not advertising Sigma-Aldrich/Merck, they simply have most of the examples and the necessary data.

---

### [*N*,*N*′-Dimethylpropylene urea (DMPU)](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/251569)

- Melting point at 1 atm: -20 °C
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 246 °C
- Flash point: 121 °C
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: Fully miscible in any proportion

### [Trimethyl phosphate](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/132195)

- Melting point at 1 atm: -46 °C
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 197 °C
- Flash point: 150 °C
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: [100 g solvent per 100 g water](http://chemister.ru/Database/properties-en.php?dbid=1&id=6758)

### [Triethyl phosphate](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/538728)

- Melting point at 1 atm: -56 °C
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 215 °C
- Flash point: 130 °C
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: [50 g solvent per 100 g water](http://chemister.ru/Database/properties-en.php?dbid=1&id=6695)

### [Dihydrolevoglucosenone (Cyrene™)](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sial/807796)

- Melting point at 1 atm: -18 °C
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 227 °C
- Flash point: 108 °C
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: Fully miscible in any proportion

### [Triethylene glycol dimethyl ether (triglyme)](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sigald/t59803)

- Melting point at 1 atm: -45 °C
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 216 °C
- Flash point: 113 °C
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: "[Very soluble](http://chemister.ru/Database/properties-en.php?dbid=1&id=15259)" (likely fully miscible in any proportion)

---

Some near misses of interest:

### [Propylene carbonate](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sigald/p52652)

- Melting point at 1 atm: -55 °C
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 240 °C
- Flash point: 132 °C
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: [**7.5 g water in 100 g solvent**](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/je60050a021)
- Note: Fully miscible with water in any proportion above 61 °C

### [Hexamethylphosphoramide (HMPA)](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/h11602)

- Melting point at 1 atm: **7 °C**
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 232 °C
- Flash point: 144 °C
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: Fully miscible in any proportion
- **NOTE: Carcinogenic**

### [gamma-Butyrolactone](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/aldrich/b103608)

- Melting point at 1 atm: -45 °C
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 204 °C
- Flash point: **98 °C**
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: Fully miscible in any proportion

### [*N*-Methyl-2-pyrrolidinone (NMP)](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/product/sigald/494496)

- Melting point at 1 atm: -24 °C
- Boiling point at 1 atm: 202 °C
- Flash point: **91 °C**
- Solubility in water at 25 °C: Fully miscible in any proportion